# Is it possible to retrieve the "width" from a format string

Tags: c++, fmt

I need a way to retrieve the "width" parameter from a `fmt::format` format string.

I **do not want** the *resulting* size of a format operation which is easy to extract with `auto size = fmt::formatted_size("{:>5.2f}", 13453453.76345f);`

```
fmt::format("{:>5.2f}", 13.23454f);
//              ^
//     I want this number (5)
```

I expect something like this

```
auto width = fmt::with_arg("{:>5.2f}");
assert(width == 5);
```

And ...
It would be nice if it worked for integers too:

```
fmt::format("{:>4d}", 42);
//              ^
//     I want this number (4)
```

Comment: What is the problem you need to solve? Why do you need the width?And why not putting the width in a variable that you pass to the `format` function (e.g. `int width = 5; fmt::format("{:>{}.2f}", 13.23454f, width);`)? Then it's easy to get the width.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, That's *exactly* what I try to avoid. I try to avoid repeating additional arguments with information that is contained in the string. Adding `{}` to the format string add too much constraints on the format string.

Comment: @user23573 You can create your own function get_width(string fmt), and in that function, you can basically measure width by placing some float value and then measuring the resulting string lengths (or parsing them).

Comment: @user23573 Alternatively, you can dig deeper into fmt to see how they managed to do it. Perhaps modify fmt to give you that specific need?

Answer (score 0):

No, width is used internally to determining the amount of padding. It is not provided through any of the public APIs. You can parse the format string and get the width using [parse_format_string](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/60c43e870387affb07de32ed4fc2794ac7a9f60d/include/fmt/format.h#L2631)  but that's an internal function.

Comment: `parse_format_string` is exactly the function I'm interested in. Does anybody have examples?